# Count of distinct multiples of n numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ where $a_i < a_{i+1}$ and a large number $K$ such that $a_n < K$.

How do I count the total number of distinct multiples $<K$ for all elements of $A$?

For example, if $A = \{3,5,10,15\}$ and $K = 200$ I want to find count all the distinct multiples of $3,5,10,$ and $15$ less than $200$.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle, I'd say.

Comment: Is this a programming problem or a paper and pencil problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed the priciple of inclusion and exclusion (PIE).

This is a good starting point:

How many integers from 1 to 100 are multiples of 2 or 3?

Solution: Let $A$ be the set of integers from 1 to 100 that are multiples of 2

$(|A|=50=floor(100/2)=floor(K/a[i])$ in the general case).

Let $B$ be the set of integers from 1 to 100 that are multiples of 3

$(|B|=33=floor(100/3))$. Now $A\cap B$ is the set of integers from 1 to 100 that are multiples of both 2 and 3, hence are multiples of 6 ($|A\cap B|=floor(100/6)=16).$ By PIE,

$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B| = 50 + 33 -16 = 67.$

This shows you how to find the number of multiples of 2 integers less than a bigger integer.  It can easily be generalised to a set of n integers using the general PIE formula given at https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/

(from which I took the whole answer from).